# Python multiprocessing with dill.load

Tags: python

I'm having great difficulties in getting functions executed in MultiProcessing Pool method that are loaded through

```
    dill.load('somefile.sav','rb')
```

The code is something like this:

```
    import dill as dill  
    import multiprocessing_on_dill as mp

    dill_func = dill.load('somefile.sav','rb')

    def some_mp_func(x):
     dill_func(x)

    if (__name__ == '__main__'):
     __spec__ = "ModuleSpec(name='builtins', loader=<class '_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter'>)" 
     x="test"
     pool = mp.Pool(processes = (8))
     pool.map(some_mp_func, x)
     pool.close()
     pool.join()
```

dill_func is an SKlearn Pipeline.

The output is:

```
NameError: name 'Y' is not defined
```

Where 'Y' is a function within dill_func, part of a Class in dill_func.

Running some_mp_func(x) without Multiprocessing runs perfectly fine, no Name errors. Any suggestions?

Comment: Apparently this issue is related to dill and Windows: https://github.com/uqfoundation/dill/issues/115. I'm trying to dump with dill.settings['recurse']=True.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLUTION: when dumping use this setting

```
    dill.settings['recurse']=True
```